# How much thrust should be applied when you set the autopilot to a specific altitude?

Tags: autopilot, thrust, throttle

After a plane takes off the pilot usually sets the autopilot to the altitude of the flight level they are about to cruise at, e.g. 30,000 ft, right? When that is the case, how much thrust should be applied during further ascent and then at the cruise altitude? Or does the autopilot do this itself as well? How would the autopilot behave if you ascend at 100% of thrust or at a thrust too low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autopilot commands the pitch and roll and uses elevator and pitch trim as well as ailerons and rollspoilers for this.
An optional auto-throttle system changes the thrust or power of the engine.

Some aircraft, not all, have an auto-throttle system, for example: Boeing 737, 747, 757, 767, 777, 787, Airbus A320 family, A330, A340, A350, A380 all have this. Other aircraft such as the Dash-8 Q400, Cessna 172 and most turboprops and piston and general aviation aircraft do not have an auto-throttle system.

In aircraft with the auto-throttle, when the system is turned on, the A/THR changes the thrust between idle and climb thrust (not full 100% thrust). So during the climb the auto-throttle advances thrust to climb thrust and keeps it there until the new altitude target is captured. During the climb the autopilot pitches up and down to maintain the set target speed. Then, upon reaching the target altitude the auto-throttle switches back to maintaining the airspeed and the autopilot pitches up and down to maintain the altitude. During the descent the auto-throttle system reduces thrust to idle.

In aircraft without an auto-throttle system, the autopilot can only change the pitch of the aircraft and you as a pilot need to feed in power for climb or reduce power for the descent. Otherwise the aircraft wont climb or descent. These autopilots may still have a flight level change mode where the autopilot maintains a set airspeed target and pitches up and down as you increase or decrease power but you still need to control the engine manually. And once the target altitude has been reached you also need to change thrust or power to fly at the desired speed.

Comment: Does the auto-throttle have to be turned on seperately or does it turn on when you turn on the cruise altitude? If the former, what do you turn on first, the altitude or the auto-throttle? And at what altitude do you usually start ascending / end descending on autopilot?

Comment: @Giovanni All of those questions depend heavily on the airplane type, the policies of the company, and the preferences of the pilot. The autothrottle is usually a separate control from the autopilot, though exceptions exist. You turn them on in whatever order the checklist for that specific plane says. For big commercial planes, the autopilot and autothrottle are typically turned on a few seconds after takeoff, and remain that way until a few seconds before landing, but they can always be turned off if needed. For smaller planes, the pilot decides.

Comment: There was an autothrottle STC add-on for the CRJ200 corporate version that I've used a few times. I didn't like it because the thrust lever friction controls were removed and the AT servo clutches remained engaged full time, the clutch slip force being your one-size-only friction level, which was too high for my liking, especially on approaches.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield I mean the usual passenger jet airliners. You put in the altitude and set the switch so that the autopilot goes there. Do you immediately afterwards have to turn on autothrottle or otherwise what throttle is best so that the plane _stays_ at the autopilot altitude?

Comment: @Giovanni There's no such thing as "usual passenger jet airliners" in this case. A 737 is going to have a different procedure than an A320. Delta Airlines has different procedures from Emirates Air. Also, what do you mean by "have to"? If you're taking a technical perspective, you don't "have to" use the autothrottle at all, any more than you "have to" use the cruise control of your car. If you're taking a procedural perspective, you "have to" turn it on when the manufacturer/company policy says you "have to".

Comment: @Giovanni, you seem to have a misconception that throttle is used to hold altitude, it isn’t. The auto pilot modulates pitch to hold altitude, power is used to control speed.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield I doubt that pilots would want to fly manually all the time at a certain flight level. So yes, they have to use the autopilot.

Comment: @Giovanni In my comment, I was talking about the auto*throttle*, not the auto*pilot*. And, no, you don't *have* to use either one (unless, of course, required by procedure). You can drive for hours without an autodriver, you can fly for hours without an autopilot.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Airline pilots need to fly at the very flight level ATC has told them. E.g. exactly at 30,000 ft which is hard to control manually. And concerning autothrottle, that was a question of mine. Obviously they don't need to use it for the autopilot to hold the altitude.

Comment: @Giovanni I am a pilot, and I can tell you, it is *not* that hard to manually hold altitude. I've flown a plane with a broken autopilot for over an hour, and never once busted an altitude restriction. Autopilots are only required in areas of [reduced vertical separation minimum](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/separation_standards/rvsm).

Comment: @Giovanni Usually the auto-throttle is armed before takeoff and is engaged after takeoff at around 1000ft or so (depends on thrust reduction height, airplane and operating procedure). The autopilot is typically used from 400ft above the ground until just prior to landing. Once auto-throttle or autopilot are engaged they remain on. You can still select new modes like climb, descent or altitude hold and the auto-throttle and autopilot handle all that for you. At any time during the flight the pilot can take manual control.